# Электронный магазин

Tags: выбор-слов, управление

Встретил вывеску на магазине, продающем электронику - "электронный магазин". Допустимо ли такое сочетание с точки зрения русского языка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да нет. Сейчас единственная ассоциация со словосочетанием "электронный магазин" — это интернет-магазин или на худой конец — автомат (кофе и прочих товаров). Впрочем, "Электронный магазин" может быть допустимо как название, своего рода "фишка", то тогда лучше как-то обыграть это в вывеске. А если ничего такого нет, то, мне кажется, это не очень-то правильно.

Comment: В качестве эксклюзива я бы назвал : Магазин "Электронский"! Притягивать будет название, как магнитом)
Чай цейлонский, магазин электронский, лес Булонский, халдей вавилонский...

Answer (score 1):

Если это магазин электроники, то он не электронный. Прилагательное от электроника - электронический - несвободно.
А если он осуществляет электронную торговлю - почему нет? Зачем такому "электронному" магазину вывеска и вообще торговая площадка? Чтобы заплпатить по Интернету - а потом прийти за товаром в строго назначенное время.

Answer (score 0):

Нет,это словосочетание не совсем удачное.Электронный, - 1.Соотносящийся с электроном,связаный с ним.2.Имеющий свойства электрона.